# Show a progress bar in new window

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

How can I create a progress bar in a new window in front of my MainWindow? Now, my prgoressbar will be showed. However, I just used the .Show() function and the window will show nothing; when I used .ShowDialog() function, then the window will show the progress bar but it will not work. I know that the difference between Show and ShowDialog is that Show will return at once. My question is how can I make my progressbar window work ?

Comment: Are you making a new reference of the Window in question? You should be able to access the controls in the new Window instance.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: `DownloadProgressWindow userControl = new DownloadProgressWindow (cnt_s);` I call my progress window in my main window.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the same logic applies to `WPF`

The solution is `WinForm` based

Form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    // i have used thread pool just to simulate virtual progress from 1 to 100
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ShowProgressHandler, form);

    form.ShowDialog();

}

private void ShowProgressHandler(object o)
{
    Form2 form = o as Form2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int i1 = i;
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => form.OnProgress(i1)));
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public event Action<int> Progress;

protected internal virtual void OnProgress(int obj)
{
    progressBar1.Value = obj;
}
```